# Loop MySQLI Query every num seconds

Tags: php

So my php mysqli displays the contents of my table once. However, I would like it to make it refresh every 10 seconds. The contents of the table will be constantly changing because of something Im adding later. I think this is the only way to display the new table data, refreshing every 10 seconds.

**What I need is something which will continually refresh the part which displays the table data infintly and will also add 1 onto my variable**

```
$tableRefresh = 0;
```

Just to prove it's working. Below is my current code.

```
$tableRefresh = 0;

$con = mysqli_connect( $svname, $username, $password, $dbname );

if (!$con) {
  die( "Connection failed due to: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected to database! <br>";


$rtMarket = "SELECT * FROM test";
$rtResult = mysqli_query($con, $rtMarket);

if (mysqli_num_rows($rtResult) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rtResult)) {
    echo "ID: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " - Value: " . $row["value"]. "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "Fetched 0 results!";
  echo "<br>";
}

echo "The table has been refreshed: $tableRefresh times.";
```

Answer (score 0):

If refreshing the entire page continuously is not an issue then use Javascript to refresh the page every 10 seconds.

```
set_interval(location.reload(), 10000);
```

Then use a session variable to count the number of refreshes.

```
session_start();
isset($_SESSION['refreshCount']) ? $_SESSION['refreshCount]++ : $_SESSION['refreshCount'] = 0;
```

The above code checks if the session variable is already set, if it is then add one to it and if it is not then initiate it.

Finally, use the session variable to display the refresh number

```
echo "The table has been refreshed: $_SESSION['refreshCount'] times.";
```